# Import Button for Custom Object

Tags: related-list, import, data-import-wizard

I have a custom object that I would like users to be able to upload new related records to. These records are the detail of a master-detail relationship. In campaigns, you can add campaign members with the data import wizard, and they automatically link to the campaign.

Is it possible to create a custom button on a related list to import the detail files via the data import wizard and have them link to the master without having to add record id#s in the .cvs file?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.